# Create frequent number sqlite queries

Tags: sql

Good evening. I created a database with 9 columns and 605 rows.
On column 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 there are numbers ranging from 1 to 90 random. Now I would like to create a query that tells me on each line how many times a number is frequent. The table is divided into 11 lines: Bari, Cagliari etc. For each city I have to count how many times a number has come out.

I await your response. Thanks.

Link a image: [enter link description here](https://photos.app.goo.gl/3zTimCYcZuYqxGqZA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you post SQL questions, it often helps to tell us what database system you're using, because the syntax is often slightly different between systems.

However, here is a query which (I think) does what you expect for most systems. You might have to tweak it.

```
WITH CTE_ESTR1 AS (
    SELECT ESTR1 AS NUM, RUOTA, COUNT(1) AS CNT
    FROM {{ your_table }}
    GROUP BY 1, 2
)
,CTE_ESTR2 AS (
    SELECT ESTR2 AS NUM, RUOTA, COUNT(1) AS CNT
    FROM {{ your_table }}
    GROUP BY 1, 2
)
,CTE_ESTR3 AS (
    SELECT ESTR3 AS NUM, RUOTA, COUNT(1) AS CNT
    FROM {{ your_table }}
    GROUP BY 1, 2
)
,CTE_ESTR4 AS (
    SELECT ESTR4 AS NUM, RUOTA, COUNT(1) AS CNT
    FROM {{ your_table }}
    GROUP BY 1, 2
)
,CTE_ESTR5 AS (
    SELECT ESTR5 AS NUM, RUOTA, COUNT(1) AS CNT
    FROM {{ your_table }}
    GROUP BY 1, 2
)
,CTE_ALL AS (
    SELECT * FROM CTE_ESTR1 
    UNION ALL SELECT * FROM CTE_ESTR2 
    UNION ALL SELECT * FROM CTE_ESTR3 
    UNION ALL SELECT * FROM CTE_ESTR4 
    UNION ALL SELECT * FROM CTE_ESTR5 
)
SELECT NUM, RUOTA, SUM(CNT) AS NUM_OCCURENCE
FROM CTE_ALL
GROUP BY NUM, RUOTA;
```

I generated it with [Rasgo](https://docs.rasgoml.com/rasgo-docs/transforms/all-transforms) automatically and then tested it in Snowflake.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, it works. I created the database with the SQLiteStudio software, locally. I would like to add the keyword "LIKE Bari" to the code. How should the code be changed?

P.S. I'm sorry, I'm self-taught, I learn by practicing.

Resolved. I added: WHERE Ruota LIKE 'Bari'

Comment: Hi Jonwick, you should probably post this question specifically as a new question, tagged with C# and SQL. Most likely posting this inside the answers section will get it removed eventually and so posting it as a new question will get you an answer fastest.

Comment: Hi Josh. Can you make me the query for late numbers? (I have to count the numbers that have not come out, when there is a number it puts me zero and then starts counting again)  You can reply to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72202988/database-sqlite3-random-numbers-came-out